# PYODBC insert select with placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2, pyodbc, db2-400

I am trying to insert a row with pyodbc to a DB2 db using a select statement.

Here is the the piece of code:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO BIUMO220.delivery_notes(id, date, provider_id)
            SELECT ?, ?, P.id
            FROM BIUMO220.providers P
            WHERE P.name = ?,
            DELIVERY_ID.get().upper(), DELIVERY_DATE.get().upper(), PROVIDER.get().upper()""")
```

All those variables come from a Tkinter form.

But when I execute the code I get this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0418 - The use of parameter marker or NULL is invalid. (-418) (SQLPrepare)')
```

I tried to execute the statement withouth placeholders (information hardcoded) and it works fine.

EDIT (DB TABLES):

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE BIUMO220.delivery_notes(
                id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                date DATE NOT NULL,
                provider_id INT NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES BIUMO220.providers(id),
                PRIMARY KEY (id))""")

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE BIUMO220.providers(
                id INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id))""")
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass in values for the parameters. See the documentation here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters

Comment: Those `XXXX.get().upper()` should not be inside the SQL string.  It should be something like `cursor.execute("""INSERT .... WHERE P.name = ?""", (DELIVERY_ID.get().upper(), ...))`.

Comment: Tried both things and I get the same exact error.

Comment: Are you able to provide [minimum reproducible example (create table, data schema) along with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited the question, is that what you wanted?

Comment: You should probably remove the tkinter tag since it is not relevant to the problem. Maybe add db2-as400 instead?

Comment: That's true, sorry. I just changed it.

Comment: It looks like your driver is quite old `System i Access` and `i5/OS`. Maybe you should get a newer driver. Parameter markers may not have even been supported by the driver back then.

Answer (score 0):

It works without placeholders because in that case your  SQL-statement is valid.

But you put placeholders where they are not valid, you cannot have them untyped in a SELECT list. For i-series, the parameter marker can appear anywhere a host-variable might appear.

The i-series returns you code "-418" which you can lookup [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=messages-sql0250-sql0499#sql0418n) (SQL0418N) which means: *"SQL0418N The statement was not processed because the statement contains an invalid use of one of the following: an untyped parameter marker, the DEFAULT keyword, or a null value.
"*

The parameter markers (placeholders) can appear in the WHERE clause mainly. See the documented restrictions at this (for Db2-LUW) [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=design-parameters-markers) and for "Db2 for i series" at [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=descriptor-parameter-markers) page.

When you want different columns in the result-set, you need to have different SQL statements prepared/executed (each of which can have different parameter markers in valid locations of the SQL).

When you want different constant values (i.e. not column-names), in the result-set, the parameter markers need to be typed with appropriate casts.